Why is $A^{-1}$ existing a necessary condition for $x$ to be unique in $Ax = b$?
Consider the equation $Ax = b$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Say we know $A$ and $b$. I am wondering why, in order for us to uniquely determine $x$, $A$ needs to be invertible: we know that if $A^{-1}$ exists, then we can uniquely determine $x$; but why is the converse, that if we can uniquely determine $x$, $A^-1$ exists, the case?
I am asking because the lack of an inverse existing is considered tantamount to our inability to uniquely find $x$, leading me to wonder why we must have an inverse here.

$A^{-1}$ only exists in the case $m=n$ , but a solution can be unique also if $m\ne n$.

However , in the case $m=n$ , the solution is unique iff $A^{-1}$ exists.

Does this (under the necessary hypothesis $m=n$) answer your question? If $A$ is a square matrix and $Ax = b$ has a unique solution for some $b$, is $A$ necessarily invertible?

If you study linear algebra, you should have seen a proof of this.

The correct statement is that whenever $Ax=b$ is solvable, the solution is unique if and only if $A$ has full column rank. When $A$ is a square matrix, the rank condition is equivalent to the existence of $A^{-1}$.

I suggest first doing the $m=n$ case then separately considering $m\gt n$ and $m\lt n$ and applying rank-nullity to each.

for rectangular,  a common approach is to write $A^T A x=  A^T b,$  then ask whether $A^T A$ is invertible. In the Kalman Filter, the favorable case is called something like "observable."

Just to put things above together:
$A$ doesn't need to be invertible. A simple counter example is
$\begin{equation}
    A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1
\end{bmatrix},
    b=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$.
However, when $m=n$, the statement is true:
Suppose $\mathbf{x}_1$ uniquely solves $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$. Then $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ must also have a unique solution, the trivial solution $\mathbf{x}_2=\mathbf{0}$ (otherwise $\mathbf{x}_1+\mathbf{x}_2\neq\mathbf{x}_1$ solves $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, contradiction). Let $\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{a}_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be column vectors of $A$. By definition, they must be linearly independent, thus $A$ is invertible (I assume you have learned the Invertible Matrix Theorem in Linear Algebra).
